# Apache thrift can not make

Tags: c++, linux, thrift, cassandra-0.7

When I'm trying to configure and make thrift 0.9.1 it gives some errors. Can anyone tell me the reason for that and what should I do to overcome this issue. Errors are shown in below.

```
user@linux-yyzo:~/WorkDir/thrift-0.9.1> make
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/user/WorkDir/thrift-0.9.1'
Making all in compiler/cpp
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/user/WorkDir/thrift-0.9.1/compiler/cpp'
make  all-am
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/user/WorkDir/thrift-0.9.1/compiler/cpp'
\
 \
/bin/sh ../../ylwrap `test -f 'src/thrifty.yy' || echo './'`src/thrifty.yy y.tab.c thrifty.cc y.tab.h thrifty.h y.output thrifty.output -- yacc -d 
../../ylwrap: line 113: yacc: command not found
make[3]: *** [thrifty.cc] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/user/WorkDir/thrift-0.9.1/compiler/cpp'
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/user/WorkDir/thrift-0.9.1/compiler/cpp'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/user/WorkDir/thrift-0.9.1'
make: *** [all] Error 2
user@linux-yyzo:~/WorkDir/thrift-0.9.1>
```

Comment: You don't have yacc installed on your system. `yacc: command not found` it's pretty clear.

Comment: I am using openSUSE, Could you please tell me how to install yacc.

Comment: Sorry I don't know the answer to that. But a quick google and I found this http://forums.opensuse.org/english/get-technical-help-here/install-boot-login/424461-yacc-lex-tool-reg.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two resources on the Thrift web site worth reading when one runs into troubles like this.

The **[Requirements](http://thrift.apache.org/docs/install/)** give a good overview about the dependencies; the **[Building From Source](http://thrift.apache.org/docs/BuildingFromSource/)** page explains build steps and configure switches briefly. Additionally, the requirements page holds some links to more specific information for builds on Ubuntu, CentOS, Windows and OS X.