# Why is Apache Thrift installation failing at make command?

Tags: thrift

I am trying to install Apache Thrift on Windows 7 via Cygwin. I tried using the [exe installer](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?path=/thrift/0.9.2/thrift-0.9.2.exe) but that didn't work (only a command prompt was opened and closed). Then I tried installing through making a build through Cygwin but ran into this error.

```
 $ make
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/f/Thrift Practice/thrift-0.9.2'
Making all in compiler/cpp
make[2]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/f/Thrift Practice/thrift-0.9.2/compiler/cpp'
make  all-am
make[3]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/f/Thrift Practice/thrift-0.9.2/compiler/cpp'
source='thriftl.cc' object='libparse_a-thriftl.o' libtool=no \
DEPDIR=.deps depmode=none /bin/sh ../../depcomp \
g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../.. -I../../lib/cpp/src/thrift  -I./src  -Wall -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused -g -O2 -std=c++11 -c -o libparse_a-thriftl.o `test -f 'thriftl.cc' || echo './'`thriftl.cc
thriftl.cc: In function ‘void yy_init_buffer(YY_BUFFER_STATE, FILE*)’:
thriftl.cc:3399:60: error: ‘fileno’ was not declared in this scope
         b->yy_is_interactive =  file ? (isatty( fileno(file) ) > 0) : 0;
                                                            ^
Makefile:751: recipe for target 'libparse_a-thriftl.o' failed
make[3]: *** [libparse_a-thriftl.o] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/f/Thrift Practice/thrift-0.9.2/compiler/cpp'
Makefile:539: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/f/Thrift Practice/thrift-0.9.2/compiler/cpp'
Makefile:531: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/f/Thrift Practice/thrift-0.9.2'
Makefile:452: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I tried changing the variable :

```
b->yy_is_interactive = 0 ;
```

but that resulted in some other error ( ‘realpath’ was not declared in this scope). I have checked through other related question [Apache thrift can not make](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19265055/apache-thrift-can-not-make)  but I have all the requirements meet to run Thrift

Comment: For typical cases there is no need for Cygwin or MinGW anymore. If you really, really absolutely want to build under Cygwin, follow the usual steps. `bootstrap.sh && configure && make && sudo make install`. No guarantees however, and I doubt that Cygwin is even a supported target.

Comment: That would be great but as I mentioned earlier the exe is failing to install anything, it just open a command prompt for a second and then closes. That was the reason I tried installing it via Cygwin. Can you tell me how I can figure out what is causing this malfunction ?  Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Why? See my answer below. You don't need Cygwin. BTW, if you used [this EXE](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?path=/thrift/0.9.2/thrift-0.9.2.exe) then you already found the compiler, which is a [command line tool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface). Enter `thrift --help` or in your case `thrift-0.9.2.exe --help` to get more info. The EXE *installer* is located somwehere else, but yes, there is one.

Comment: Okay it worked, I mistook the compiler as a "double click" exe installer. Practiced some examples with it and it succeeded. Thanks for the prompt reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the EXE installer in Windows, there is no need for Cygwin. The EXE installer installs Thrift.EXE.

The runtime library can be used out of the [repository branch](https://github.com/apache/thrift/tree/0.9.2), there are build projects for Visual Studio.

And on top of it there's even a [VS build project for the Thrift compiler itself](https://github.com/apache/thrift/blob/0.9.2/compiler/cpp/compiler.vcxproj). Isn't that great?

---

<sub>PS: https://thrift.apache.org/docs/install/windows is slightly outdated. Thanks for the heads up.</sub>